# return with format() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I want to return in this format => "HH:MM:SS" (in a clock format and the HH, MM, SS change depend on the question)
I know how to print it but I don't know how to return it.

Comment: Please show your code, what result you expect, and what result you're getting.

Comment: replace the word `print` with `return` and remove the brackets?

Comment: @Sayse You don't even need to remove the brackets :)

Comment: @Barmar - You dont, but you should :)

Answer (score 2):

As you can do

```
print(f"{hour:02}:{minute:02}:{second:02}")
```

You can

```
return f"{hour:02}:{minute:02}:{second:02}"
```

If you prefer to use `format` it would be

```
return "{0:02}:{1:02}:{2:02}".format(hour, minute, second)
```